# PFFacebookUtils logIn sometimes creates new user, sometimes logs in

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

So I am using parse.com, with automatic anonymous user, and login/signup with facebook (iOS). The problem is that sometimes it logs in properly, and othertimes (most times) it creates a new user, that appears to be anonymous. This happens both with new users (anonymous -> make non-anonymous and link with facebook) and users logging in (anonymous -> log in with facebook already linked).

I'm using essentially the same code provided in the parse.com documentation. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code when tapping a the facebook button.

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"publish_actions"];
[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissions block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        //try refreshing the user in case that is the problem (its not, sometimes?).
        [user refresh:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR. %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", user);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            if (!user) {
                NSString *errorMessage = nil;
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"User cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    errorMessage = @"User cancelled the Facebook login.";
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
                    errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
                }
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Log In Error"
                                                                message:errorMessage
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            } else {
                if (user.isNew) {
                    NSLog(@"User for Facebook! (new user)");

                    [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];

                    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
                    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                        if (!error) {
                            NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
                            NSString *name = userData[@"name"];
                            user[@"displayName"] = name;
                            user[@"facebookName"] = name;
                            user[@"facebookId"] = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

                            [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];

                            [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                if (error) {
                                    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                                }
                                [self showProfileSetupView];

                                [Global checkAndUpdateTrophyWithIdentifier:TROPHYConnectWithFacebook inViewController:self.navigationController];
                            }];
                            NSLog(@"User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");

                        } else {
                            if ([error.userInfo[FBErrorParsedJSONResponseKey][@"body"][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"]) {
                                NSLog(@"The facebook session was invalidated");
                            }
                            else {
                                NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
                            }
                        }
                    }];
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"User logged in through Facebook!");

                    if (!user[@"displayName"] || !user[@"facebookName"] || !user[@"facebookId"]) {

                        [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];

                        FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
                        [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                            if (!error) {
                                NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
                                NSString *name = userData[@"name"];
                                user[@"displayName"] = name;
                                user[@"facebookName"] = name;
                                user[@"facebookId"] = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

                                [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                                    }
                                }];
                                [self.delegate userSignUpViewControllerDidLogIn:self];

                            } else {
                                if ([error.userInfo[FBErrorParsedJSONResponseKey][@"body"][@"error"][@"type"] isEqualToString:@"OAuthException"]) {
                                    NSLog(@"The facebook session was invalidated");
                                }
                                else {
                                    NSLog(@"Some other error: %@", error);
                                }
                            }


                        }];
                    }
                    else {
                        [self.delegate userSignUpViewControllerDidLogIn:self];
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    });

}];
```

Comment: check in your parse.com and fb app settings if you've allowed anonymous login

Comment: I have everthing turned "on" in the parse.com settings: anonymous login, facebook login, user&password, twitter. I don't know what you mean by fb settings for anonymous login. Also I am not approved yet in FB (likely due to this issue), so I have a couple test accounts that are authorized for the app

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the user's `email` field set and you try to Facebook Login with a user that has the same email, Parse creates a new empty User in the database with FB authentication. You probably wanted to link FB Authenticated user with the existing user having the same email?

If that is the case, you could check if the anonymous/email user is connected with facebook and if he's not, delete the `email` field before connecting.

Check connection with facebook: `[PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]`